# How to write a nested xml using DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I used DataSet to load a schema from following xml file;

```
<node id="0">
    <node id="1"/>
</node>
```

Then I cleared this dataset and filled data in. When I tried to invoke WriteXml method of my dataset, it threw a exception said:

Cannot proceed with serializing DataTable "node". It contains a DataRow which has multiple parent rows on the same Foreign Key.

But I am so sure that there is no multiple parent rows in my data. Some one said I shoud set dataset's EnforceConstraints as false but it didn't work.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have some other reasons to use DataSet.
BTW: I have found the root cause of this exception. I have setted two different parents to different tables for some rows of 'node' table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSet is specifically for data that matches a relational-style schema. For all other XML work, you should use one of the XML APIs, such as LINQ to XML (XElement), XmlReader, XmlDocument, or XPathDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using XElement for this kind of tasks. If you really need DataSets at a certain point, you can easily convert XElements to DS and back.